# How to set the version number reported by `$ tmux -V`, during the compilation of a `tmux` package?

Tags: tmux

I'm compiling [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux) from its source code via a script which looks like this:

```
set -e
DIR="${HOME}/Programs/"
build() {
  [[ -d "${DIR}" ]] || mkdir -p "${DIR}"
  cd "${DIR}"
  if [[ ! -d tmux ]]; then
    git clone https://github.com/tmux/tmux
  fi
  cd tmux
  git stash
  git checkout master
  git pull
  make clean; make distclean
  sh autogen.sh
  ./configure
  make
}
install() {
  dpkg -r tmux
  checkinstall --pkgname tmux --pkgversion '9999:9999.9999' -y
}
build
install
```

It compiles and installs tmux, as expected.
But there's still one issue, which is the version reported by `$ tmux -V`:

```
$ tmux -V
tmux master
```

It reports `tmux master`, while I would prefer `tmux X.Y`, `X.Y` being the version of the latest release.
For example, at the moment, the latest release is [`2.8`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/releases/tag/2.8), so I would like `$ tmux -V` to output `tmux 2.8`.

Is there any way to change this output?

I've looked at the output of `./configure --help`, and searched for an option to set the version of the tmux process, but couldn't find one.

For the moment, I've included a `sed` command in my script so that it automatically edits the file `configure.ac`, and assigns a big version number `99.99` (I don't know how to programmatically get the version number of the latest release):

```
sh autogen.sh
sed -i 's/AC_INIT(tmux, master)/AC_INIT(tmux, 99.99)/' configure.ac
./configure
```

Is there a better way?

---

The reason why I ask this question is because I use the [tmux-open](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-open) plugin, which doesn't work as expected when `$ tmux -V` outputs `tmux master`.

The latter uses [this line of code](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-open/blob/f99d3189c445188eae5fa9bfeabc95df16deca92/scripts/helpers.sh#L46) to determine the version of the current tmux process:

```
$ tmux_version="$(tmux -V | cut -d ' ' -f 2)"
```

The plugin then uses this variable [to determine the syntax of the commands installing key bindings](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-open/blob/f99d3189c445188eae5fa9bfeabc95df16deca92/open.tmux#L106-L131).

The key bindings are not installed on my machine, and I think it's due to the output of `$ tmux -V`.
Because if I replace [this line](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-open/blob/master/scripts/helpers.sh#L48) in the plugin:

```
if [[ $tmux_version == $1 ]]
```

with this line:

```
if [[ $tmux_version == $1 ]] || [[ $tmux_version == 'master' ]]
```

Then the plugin correctly installs its key bindings.

Comment: Does `git describe` or ... tag show anything useful?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Ah yes, you're right `git describe` gives `2.8-66-g71d2ab1`. I'll use this as the version number, thank you very much.

Comment: I think if you set the VERSION env variable before running `configure` that will set the version in the right .h file. So `VERSION=2.8-66-g71d2ab1 ./configure && make`

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol I've tried `VERSION="$(git describe)" ./configure && make`, and `VERSION=2.8-66-g71d2ab1 ./configure && make`, but both give the same output `tmux master`. Maybe I should use another variable, though. Anyway, thank you very much for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insert a line like:

```
sed '/AC_INIT/s/master/m4_esyscmd_s([git describe])/' -i configure.ac
```

before the `sh autogen.sh` call in your script.

based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526939/how-to-insert-git-based-version-in-autoconf-managed-project)